# Is there any difference between "sticking to" and "stuck on"?

Tags: word-usage

See these two expressions:

> Every time I park my car here, there are tons of fliers **stuck on** the windshield when I come back to pick it up.
>
> Every time I park my car here, there are tons of fliers **sticking to** the windshield when I come back to pick it up.

Are **sticking to** or **stuck on** both correct here in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer here: yes! Both are correct. They have no discernable difference in meaning and I'd say either is equally likely to be said. I can't think of any reason why you'd choose one or the other, so use either at will!

Comment: But be careful to distinguish this from being *stuck on* somebody else, and from *sticking it to* them! :)